# document.write inside script does not perform the script

Tags: javascript, document.write

According to the instructions that I am following these codes below should be able to embed a button that would perform a certain function.

```
<script>
document.write('<scriptsrc="sourcefile/filename.js">/script>')
</script>
```

The problem is that the above code displays `/script>` instead of displaying the button that the js file should display once run. Now when I try to edit it this way

```
<script>
document.write('<scriptsrc="sourcefile/filename.js"></script>')
</script>
```

') is displayed which clearly means that the first `</script>` closes the first `<script>` tag which should close the second one instead.

sorry cause I find it hard to explain it further.

Comment: Need space between script and src .

Comment: Try this, I've seen it used commonly: `document.write('<sc' + 'ript src="sourcefile/filename.js"></sc' + 'ript>')`

Comment: okay I'll try that and see if it would be able to fix my problem. thanks

Comment: separating `<sc` had fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to include a javascript file into the current html page.

As described in http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write

> That's convenient, but a bad way, because loading a script may block the rest of page from rendering.

Using DOM is a preferred way, other than the example posted on that page, below is how twitter does it.

```
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
    js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```